# docker-compose doesn't mount volumes correct for django container

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

Running Docker on Windows 10 with WSL 2 Ubuntu on it. I have the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu

#base directory
ENV HOME /root
#subdirectory name for the REST project
ENV PROJECT_NAME django_project
#subdirectory name of the users app
ENV APP_NAME users

#set the working directory
WORKDIR $HOME

#install Python 3, the Django REST framework and the Cassandra Python driver
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt -y install python3-pip 2> /dev/null
RUN pip3 install djangorestframework
RUN pip3 install cassandra-driver

#initialize the project (blank project) and creates a folder called $PROJECT_NAME
#with manager.py on its root directory
RUN django-admin startproject $PROJECT_NAME .
#install an app in the project and create a folder named after it
RUN python3 manage.py startapp $APP_NAME

ENV CASSANDRA_SEEDS cas1

ENTRYPOINT ["python3","manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

I build a image with `docker build -t django-img .` and then I have the following `.yaml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  django_c:
    container_name: django_c
    image: django-img
    environment:
      - CASSANDRA_SEEDS='cas1'
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    volumes:
      - /mnt/c/Users/claud/docker-env/django/django_project:/django_project
```

When I run `docker-compose up -d` inside **django-project** folder (.yml and Dockerfile are there), I get the container running, but I can't see in the host any file from the container. If I run `ls` in the container, however, I see all files are there:

[image]

**How am I supposed to edit the container files using an editor in my host?**

p.s.: I've already tested the volume slashes ("/") with another container and they work fine since I'm using WSL.

**ADDITION**
Here the content of my container folders using relative paths, I tried

```
volumes:
      - /mnt/c/Users/claud/docker-env/django/django_project:/root/django_project
```

but it still did not show the files in the host.
[image]

Comment: Can you use a Python virtual environment, without Docker, for day-to-day development?  That won't run into trouble like this since it doesn't have a filesystem isolation layer; it runs directly on your host files and you can use an ordinary IDE workflow.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that your volume mount refers to the *absolute* path `/django_project`, but you specify `WORKDIR $HOME` which is `/root` in your **Dockerfile**. An additional clue is that you see your files when you `ls -la ./django_project` in the container using a *relative* path.

I'll bet you can fix the problem by updating your **docker-compose.yml** `django_c` service definition to specify `/root/django_project` as your volume mount instead:

```yaml
volumes:
    - /mnt/c/Users/claud/docker-env/django/django_project:/root/django_project
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried what you said and it still doesn't work. I added a printscreen of the container folders to the question above (updated).

Comment: What does `docker exec -it django_c pwd` return? I'll bet it's `/root`